# How to dynamically add/remove QML properties inside C++?

Tags: c++, qt, reflection, qml

For example, an empty QObject-based class defined in C++. It's created from QML. Then C++ adds some properties to it via `setProperty`. But they aren't becoming accessible by QML.

Other example: use `setContextObject` and then start adding properties to that C++ object. No effect on QML.

How to make it work?

**update**

I see two options: private API (MetaObject builder) and code generation for QML items at runtime.

Comment: IIRC QMl doesn't support dynamic properties. QML code generation is easy, I use it extensively.

Comment: @TOMATO, setProperty doesn't affect the QML side when new property is created. Also, I've discovered another obvious tool for property creation: QQmlPropertyMap, but it doesn't solve the fundamental problem with binding that fails and then not reevaluating when the property appears. So, the close votes are understandable and I'll probably redesign the application to create things from QML script instead of scripting in the C++ code.

Comment: @TOMATO - nothing in the link you posted suggests they are supported. setProperty() is not even accessible from QML, neither is property() for that matter. I find this rather odd, since QML itself heavily uses dynamism, I haven't tested whether dynamic QObject properties are accessible from QML via the regular syntax, i.e. `obj.someProp`. Also there remains the issue with notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [QQmlPropertyMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlpropertymap.html). It allows you to add properties dynamically. It's usually better to predefine values through qt models in C++ though, and there aren't many good use cases for using QQmlPropertyMap.

There actually several ways to do this, [this article has a great explanations.](https://machinekoder.com/creating-qml-properties-dynamically-runtime-c/)

Comment: Read the comments to the question.